# Run Video with MediaElement from root app

Tags: c#, wpf, video, mediaelement

I want to get the address of a video file that exits in one of my application`s folder,for example i have below code:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="meShowClip" 
 Source="G:\Clip\ANIMFORCD.MPG"     
 FlowDirection="LeftToRight" 
 Width="800" Height="600" />
```

This code run correctly.

I want to change the address to a relative one. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the MSDN documentation about [`MediaElement.Source`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement.source.aspx). There you have `Source` property.

There you have example with relative path.

You have to remove `G:\Clip` from your path, but you have to be sure that the video file is in your executable folder.

This should work:

```
<MediaElement x:Name="meShowClip" 
 Source="ANIMFORCD.MPG" 
 FlowDirection="LeftToRight" 
 Width="800" Height="600" />
```

Your folder where you have the executable file should look like bellow:

```
──┬─ Your folder
  ├─── Executable.exe
  ├─── ANIMFORCD.MPG
  └─── Other files...
```

Comment: what is `Executable.exe`?where is it?

Comment: It's your executable file from `bin` directory.